# Automating opening a PDF from Preview.app in preferred PDF editor

Tags: automator, preview, sharing, services

When having a PDF file open in Preview.app, I'd like to click a menu item or keyboard hotkey to open the same file in my preferred PDF editor (f.x. PDF Expert).

I suppose it could be done by creating a Service or adding PDF Expert to the Share menu. I'm rather new to Mac/macos but have previous coding/scripting experience. So;

1. How could I with a Service in Automator get the path of the currently opened file in the Preview.app?
2. I suppose it should be possible to add a third-party app like PDF Expert to the Share menu. If so, how?

Comment: Really great question. I've just tried making a Quick Action/Service that receives the current PDF in Preview.app, but it doesn't show up in the Services menu in Preview. Xcode no longer offers an 'Application Extension' template when you start a new project (as Apple's documentation suggests).

Comment: Thanks anyway for your input, @benwiggy :-)